# How does youtube's report bug tool takes a screenshot of you screen?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, youtube

If you go on the bottom of the page there's a "Report bug" link.

They let you highlight parts of the screen and sent it along with the bug description.

Any idea of how this could be implemented?

Answer (score 3):

It uses Google's Feedback tool, which is a *heavy* implementation of JavaScript.

Taking a look at their script, they even have a JavaScript-ported version of a JPG encoder that they use to render the user-modified HTML page into an image, which I assume is then AJAX'd on over to Google when the user hits send.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to take a screenshot of your browser using javascript(even if it was possible it'd require your permission).

So maybe they don't take a screenshot. Maybe they just store the url & coordinates of the rectangle you select(and other usual stuff like your browser details, screen resolution, OS etc.).

With that information they can launch the url on the server side and take screenshots there.